# Can an apartment complex add a monthly "amenity fee" (that is not in the rental agreement) on top of the rent?

Tags: florida, rent

This is about an apartment complex in Florida. The complex was sold and the new owners decided to add a $20 monthly "amenity fee" to all existing tenants who had signed a lease months before the new management took over.

The rental contract in this particular complex is about 30 pages long and very specific, covering everything from parking to pets and the use of amenities. The contract does not mention this fee or a possibility of such a fee in the future.

Is it legal for new management to add a fee after lease contracts were signed by tenant and previous management?

Comment: At mid-lease, at renewal, or to people renting month to month anyway?

Comment: @Damila thank you, I updated the question to make it clearer that this was mid-lease.